# How many objects boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor do I need to have to accept connections in multiple threads?

Tags: boost-asio

I use a pool of ten threads for acceptors (listeners), which are accept connections and run tasks of their processing in other threads. In this case, I need one or more of the acceptor object?

```
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service_acceptors;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work_acceptors(io_service_acceptors);

    // Do I need a single object or many like threads "thr_grp_acceptors"?:
    // std::vector<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor> acpt_grp_acceptors
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service_acceptors,
        ba::ip::tcp::endpoint(ba::ip::tcp::v4(), port)); 

    std::vector<boost::thread> thr_grp_acceptors;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        thr_grp_acceptors_.emplace_back(
            boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_acceptors));

    acceptor_.async_accept(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd and other **acceptors** will not be able to **bind()** into port, so no, you cannot use many acceptors on same port. You can run many **async_accept** at a time, their handlers can fire in different threads. But, in my application i have only one active **async_accept** at a time and its enough for me under heavy load.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any sense do this in the NUMA-system: create separate pools of threads for each CPU (not cores), bind these threads (set affinity) to cores of this CPU, and for each pool to create one acceptor binded (set affinity) to the same CPU? Because sync between two CPUs and two Cores in single CPU have different latency.

Comment: @Alex i think you will not be able to get benefit from such lowlewel optimizations, while using such highlevel framework as ASIO

Comment: Ok. But how many connections I can proccess by using boost::asio or how many (around how much) connections you have reached on your hardware in a heavy load project?

Comment: @Alex currently we have about 30k connections on each frontend. CPU is about 60% idle, load average 1.. Currently we have bottleneck on memory(8G) and fd descriptors, its subject to optimizations soon